# Can't autowire Neo4jTemplate - no qualifying bean found

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

I'm pretty new to Spring & even newer to Spring Data and I'm hoping somebody can tell me where I'm going wrong, I'm sure it's something pretty stupid but just can't seem to figure it out.

What I'm trying to do is run a very simple Spring Boot application that then uses Neo4jTemplate to populate the database but I keep getting the error below

The version of Neo4j I have installed is 2.1.6, I'm wondering if this is a version compatibility issue but can't seem to find what versions of Spring Data are compatibile with which versions of Neo4j.

**Error**

```
2015-02-10 16:34:53.022  WARN 10320 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate hello.Application.template; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:26)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate hello.Application.template; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:298)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:494)
    ... 17 common frames omitted

2015-02-10 16:34:53.024  INFO 10320 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/workspace/simple-neo4j-testing-master/src/main/resources, file:/C:/workspace/simple-neo4j-testing-master/src/main/resources, file:/C:/workspace/simple-neo4j-testing-master/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j/2.1.2/neo4j-2.1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-test/1.1.10.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-test-1.1.10.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-compiler-1.9/2.0.3/neo4j-cypher-compiler-1.9-2.0.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0/2.0.3/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0-2.0.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-dsl/2.0.1/neo4j-cypher-dsl-2.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.0.8.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-primitive-collections/2.1.2/neo4j-primitive-collections-2.1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-graph-algo/2.1.2/neo4j-graph-algo-2.1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.0.3.Final/hibernate-validator-5.0.3.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.7/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.8.4/aspectjrt-1.8.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/parboiled/parboiled-scala_2.10/1.1.6/parboiled-scala_2.10-1.1.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.0.8.RELEASE/spring-context-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.0.0/classmate-1.0.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.7/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-udc/2.1.2/neo4j-udc-2.1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.7/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/net/sf/opencsv/opencsv/2.0/opencsv-2.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec/1.1.1/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.0.8.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.1.10.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.1.10.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-kernel/2.1.2/neo4j-kernel-2.1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/mockito/mockito-core/1.9.5/mockito-core-1.9.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.8.4.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.2/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.13/snakeyaml-1.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru/1.3.1/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.1.10.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.1.10.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.0.8.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.1.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.1.GA.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher/2.1.2/neo4j-cypher-2.1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.3/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.7/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-jmx/2.1.2/neo4j-jmx-2.1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-test/4.0.8.RELEASE/spring-test-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-lucene-index/2.1.2/neo4j-lucene-index-2.1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/parboiled/parboiled-core/1.1.6/parboiled-core-1.1.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-graph-matching/2.1.2/neo4j-graph-matching-2.1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-core/3.6.2/lucene-core-3.6.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.1.10.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.1.10.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.0.8.RELEASE/spring-core-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.0.8.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.0.8.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.4/aspectjweaver-1.8.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.2/logback-core-1.1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1/2.1.2/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1-2.1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-commons/2.1.2/neo4j-cypher-commons-2.1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-neo4j/3.1.5.RELEASE/spring-data-neo4j-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.4/scala-library-2.10.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/objenesis/objenesis/1.0/objenesis-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.1.10.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.1.10.RELEASE.jar]
2015-02-10 16:34:53.025 ERROR 10320 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate hello.Application.template; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:26)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate hello.Application.template; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:298)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:494)
    ... 17 common frames omitted

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate hello.Application.template; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:26)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate hello.Application.template; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:298)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:494)
    ... 17 more
```

**Main Class**

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


@Transactional
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

 @Autowired
    Neo4jTemplate template;

public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    UpdateDatabase update = new UpdateDatabase();

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

}
```

**Application Context**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />


    <context:component-scan base-package="hello" />
    <context:spring-configured />

    <neo4j:config storeDirectory="data/sample-db" base-package="hello.domain" />
    <neo4j:repositories base-package="hello.repositories" />

</beans>
```

**POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-neo4j-testing</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.10.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
             <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>neo4j</id>
            <name>Neo4j</name>
            <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!! I've tried looking at question "[Could not autowire. No beans of Neo4jTemplate type found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400631/could-not-autowire-no-beans-of-neo4jtemplate-type-found)" but unfortunately didn't solve my issue.

Comment: Are you sure that locations = "classpath:applicationContext.xml" points to your xml correctly? Try to remove the neo4j template and create some dummy bean in hello package to see if that autowires..

Comment: @user3250562 Did you ever come to a resolution to this issue? I've hit the same issue as well, and am looking for the same answer! Thanks!

Comment: In the end I moved away totally from using XML and instead used a Neo4jConfigurationNeo4jConfiguration class pretty much like the example here: http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-neo4j/

Answer (score 0):

In the end I moved to something more like the example here: http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-neo4j/ extending Neo4jConfiguration which proved a lot easier overall.

When creating the bean to connect to the remote URL I used:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService(@Value("${neo4j.database.location}") String dbUrl) {
    logger.info("Connecting to database at {}",dbUrl);
    return new SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase(dbUrl);
}
```

The example above has the location as a parameter which I also found useful